# getopt_long using flag struct member

Tags: c, long-integer, getopt

I am trying to adapt the example in the man page for getopt_long so that it uses the flag member of the structure.
But I can't get past the compiler complaining about the way I initialize the flags variable.
I change only one line from the code in the man page, see below, but when I try to compile I get:

```
gcc -Wall -c gnu_get_lopt.c
gnu_get_lopt.c: In function ‘main’:
gnu_get_lopt.c:20:51: error: initializer element is not constant
                    {"verbose", no_argument,       &verbose,  9 },
                                                   ^
gnu_get_lopt.c:20:51: note: (near initialization for ‘long_options[3].flag’)
```

The other questions re getopt_long here seem to be able to use this method.
What am I doing wrong?

pgmer6809

here is the beginning of the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>     /* for printf */ 
#include <stdlib.h>    /* for exit */ 
#include <getopt.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int c;                  
    int digit_optind = 0;
    int verbose;

    while (1) {
        int this_option_optind = optind ? optind : 1;
        int option_index = 0;
        static struct option long_options[] = {
 /* Option,    has_arg,       flags,  Val */
            {"add",     required_argument, 0,  0 },
            {"append",  optional_argument, 0,  0 },
            {"delete",  required_argument, 0,  0 },
       /*   {"verbose", no_argument,       0,  0 },          // Original GNU provided line.   */
            {"verbose", no_argument,       &verbose,  9 },   /* changed line to use flag    */
            {"create",  required_argument, 0, 'c'}, 
            {"file",    required_argument, 0,  0 },
            {0,         0,                 0,  0 }  
        };

        c = getopt_long(argc, argv, "abc:d:012",
                 long_options, &option_index);
        if (c == -1)        // no more options
            break;      // break from while

  <---- remaining program omitted for brevity ------>
 } /* end main */
```

Comment: StackOverflow seems overly picky about formatting. In the above post I had the code as code with ctl+K, and the text re the compiling and the error messages as a block quote. SO would not let me post the question until I formatted the block quote as code. (which it isn't) furthermore they did not tell me which part of the post they objected to. I had to randomly format various parts of the question as code until finally the question was accepted. pgmer6809

Answer (score 1):

`long_options` is declared `static`. It means that the initialization for the variable needs to be a *constant expression*, the compiler needs to be able to "compute" it at compile time. Yet `int verbose` is a variable that will be created upon entering main function, the address `&verbose` of the variable is not known at compile time.

You can do one of:

- Remove the `static` keyword from `long_options` definition.
- Move `verbose` variable definition to file scope.
- Add the `static` keyword to the variable `verbose`.

As you can see [in the documentation for getopt_long](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt-Long-Option-Example.html) the `verbose_flag` variable is declared at file scope and with `static`. Because of that, the `&verbose_flag` is a constant expression and may be used in initialization of other `static` variable.

For more information I can advise to read about [constant expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/constant_expression) and [storage durations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration).

Comment: Thanks very much for the quick reply. Your explanation of the effect of static is even better than the one at the link you gave me. Putting static int verbose got rid of the compile error of course. Thanks again.